# View contents in default spring boot cache

Tags: spring-boot, caching

How can i view all keys and values in spring boot default cache.

I am not using any external cache /dependency.
I am using spring boot default caching capability with @EnableCaching.

Since i am not using any native cache and relying on spring boot default cache so cache.getNativeCache() is not giving me anything to iterate through.Is there any other way to view cache contents?.

Note-: We have function to view value based on key but i am looking for a function to view cache contents at once or if it can give me all keys in cache so that i can query cache one by one to view all contents.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your `@Cacheable` got a cacheName.

`@Cacheable(cacheNames = "yourCacheName", key = "#yourKey")`

You can see your cache Object throught `CacheManager` of SpringBoot.

You can inject `CacheManager` through `@Autowired`

```
@Autowired
private CacheManager cacheManager;
```

```
System.out.println(cacheManager.getCache("yourCacheName").getNativeCache());
```

It will give you key and value for your cache.

SpringBoot cache uses `ConcurrentHashMap` to store data.

If your data prints object like `[Ljava.lang.Object;@2f361b89`

you can convert your object to byteArray and then reverse back to String for readable print.

Hope it helps.

Comment: It is not printing anything  in logs even-though i am having cache created and objects present.

Comment: Can you please show your method that is using `@Cacheable` if it doesn't bother you.

Comment: @Cacheable(value = "students", key = "#id", unless="#result==null")
  public Shipments findById(String id) {
    log.info("fetching for shipment id {} ", id);
    List<Shipments> shipments = null;
    if (id != null) {
      shipments = queryDocuments(Constants.SHIPMENT_SEARCH_QUERY, id, id);
    }
    return CollectionUtils.isEmpty(shipments) ? null : shipments.get(0);
  }